# Receive HTTP data in multiple passes

Tags: perl, sockets

I'm writing a custom HTTP server to serve my own JavaScript applications.

Getting headers from the browser is pretty straightforward with this code

```
$data_length = 0;
$client_data = "";

while ( <$client_socket> ) {

    if ( /Content-Length: (\d+)/ ) {
        $data_length = $1;
    }

    $client_data .= $_;
    last if ( $_ =~ /^\s*$/ );    # end of headers
}

# Receiving the body-entity (POST data) is where things start getting unpleasant.

$bytes_read  = 0;
$bytes_total = 0;

{
    use bytes;

    $client_data_body = "";
    $bytes_to_read    = $data_length;
    $count_recieve    = 0;

    while ( $bytes_to_read > 0 ) {

        print "Bytes to read: $bytes_to_read\n";

        $client_socket->recv( $client_data_body, $bytes_to_read );
        $bytes_read = length $client_data_body;
        $bytes_total += $bytes_read;
        $bytes_to_read = $bytes_to_read - $bytes_read;
        $client_data .= $client_data_body;

    }

}
```

The above code almost always hangs at `recv()` after some iterations. `sysread()` behaves the same way.

This is a actual output from the above script

```
Bytes to read: 48821
Bytes to read: 35168
Bytes to read: 24245
Bytes to read: 7687
```

At that point the script waits forever. If I click 'stop' in the browser I get infinitely many `Bytes to read: 7687`

```
Bytes to read: 7687
Bytes to read: 7687
Bytes to read: 7687
Bytes to read: 7687
Bytes to read: 7687
Bytes to read: 7687
Bytes to read: 7687
Bytes to read: 7687
Bytes to read: 7687
Bytes to read: 7687
Bytes to read: 7687
Bytes to read: 7687
Bytes to read: 7687
Bytes to read: 7687
```

Of course sometimes the numbers would be different from these, except the last one, which seems stuck between 7100 and 7800.

Very, very rarely the script won't hang and would do it's job the way I want it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, NEVER EVER USE `use bytes;`. Any of use it is inherently buggy. Good thing it didn't actually do anything here. Remove it!

---

As for your endless stream of calls `recv`, it's because you didn't check for EOF or error. What follows is code that does what you want:

```
my $body = '';
while ($bytes_to_read) {
   my $rv = sysread($client_socket, $body, $bytes_to_read, length($body));
   die("Read failed: $!") if !defined($rv);
   die("Read failed: Premature EOF") if !$rv;
   $bytes_to_read -= $rv;
}
```

I switched from `recv` to `sysread` since it makes more sense for a stream protocol like TCP.

All together, you want

```
my $body;
if ($request_method eq 'POST') {
   $body = '';
   if (defined($body_length)) {
      # Content-Length provided.
      my $bytes_to_read = $body_length;
      while ($bytes_to_read) {
         my $rv = sysread($client_socket, $body, $bytes_to_read, length($body));
         die("Read failed: $!") if !defined($rv);
         die("Read failed: Premature EOF") if !$rv;
         $bytes_to_read -= $rv;
      }
   } else {
      # Content-Length not provided.
      while (1) {
         my $rv = sysread($client_socket, $body, 64*1024, length($body));
         die("Read failed: $!") if !defined($rv);
         last if !$rv;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: I just tried your code. It still hangs at the second iteration. When I click 'stop' all of the remaining data is recieved

Comment: If it hangs, it means fewer than `$body_length` bytes have arrived.

Comment: I had to call shutdown($client_socket, 1); before reading from socket. Now works like a charm

Comment: Nonsense. If you do that, you won't be able to send a response.